# Order items in TsConfig / TCEForms

Tags: typo3, tsconfig

How it is possible to order the items by using TCEForms/ pageTS?
For example if another header_layout (101) is added to place this after 1.

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout {
addItems {
            101 = LLL:EXT:site_template/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:header_layout.custom_header
        }
        orderItems = 1,101,2,3
    }
```

E.g. something like `orderItems` but this isn't a valid pageTs property.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that with a custom `itemsProcFunc` ([documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#itemsprocfunc)) you define for this field. E.g. in your own extension in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php` ([documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/ExtendingTca/StoringChanges/Index.html#storing-in-the-overrides-folder)):

`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['header_layout']['config']['itemsProcFunc'] = 'MyVendor\MyExtension\TtContentHeaderLayout->sortItems';`